# why is std::less a functor?

Tags: c++, templates

Why is less a functor rather then a templated function like myless below? Why did the committee decide on that and where can I go for further reading? Also does the C++11 standard explain why the committee made certain decisions?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

#if 1

template <class T> struct stdless {
  bool operator() (const T& x, const T& y) const {return x<y;}
  typedef T first_argument_type;
  typedef T second_argument_type;
  typedef bool result_type;
};

#else
    #define stdless std::less
#endif

//bool myless(int a, int b) { return a<b; }
template<class T>
bool myless(T a, T b) { return a<b; }

int main()
{
    vector<int> a{5, 3, 1,6};

    myless(5, 6);
    stdless<int>()(5, 6);

    auto fn1=stdless<int>();
    fn1(5,9);
    auto fn2=myless<int>;
    fn2(5,9);

    sort(a.begin(), a.end(), myless<int>);
    sort(a.begin(), a.end(), less<int>());

    for(auto b=a.begin(); b!=a.end(); ++b)
        cout << *b<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Partial specializations want a word with you (`T*`, for example).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why use functors over functions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6451866/why-use-functors-over-functions)

Comment: You can potentially provide that *specialization* in a different way. The standard could just mandate the behavior, and the implementation would use an interface and dispatch to an implementation function using tag-dispatch or any similar approach (SFINAE being the new golden hammer could also be used there)

Comment: @PiotrNycz: Not really a duplicate. While they share a common set of concerns, there are specifics of `std::less` that make the question a bit more specific

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are different reasons for that. The first one, is that it is easier for the compiler to inline the call to `operator()` on a functor than to inline a call through a pointer to function (when the code doing the call is not inlined itself).

Beyond that performance advantage, there are bigger design considerations at hand with different uses of the `std::less<>` functor. In particular consider any of the sorted containers, like `std::set<T,Comparator>`. You cannot pass a pointer to function directly as a type, so to be able to use your `myless` the definition of the set would have to be `std::set<T,bool (*)(T,T)>`, now the next problem here is that pointers don't have sensible *default* constructor that would do what you want, so user code must provide the function pointer on construction of the container, which is a potential for errors.

```
std::set<int, bool(*)(int,int)> s(&myless);
```

It is simple to just forget to pass the function pointer (`std::set<int,bool(*)(int,int)> s;`) and that will get you the wrong pointer and cause undefined behavior. In the case of a functor this is not a problem, the compiler will default construct the comparator member and that will be a valid object.