# what's the advantage of defining a class instead of a function in some c++ standard library?

Tags: c++, oop, stl

Recently I noticed that C++ std::less is a class,although it simply compares the values of two objects.Here is a sample code:

```
template <class T> struct less {
  bool operator() (const T& x, const T& y) const {return x<y;}
  typedef T first_argument_type;
  typedef T second_argument_type;
  typedef bool result_type;
};
```

so what is the advantage of defining a class instead of a funciton?
and I also wonder why using the 'const' keyword despite there is no data member in the class?

Comment: It's hard to give an answer _in general_. In this case, it's likely for consistency with other functors in the standard library. In general it's so "normal functions" can hold state (like classes and structs). As for "why const" --- because it's a good practice to mark everything as `const` as possible.

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37635300/function-pointer-vs-functors-in-c

Comment: `typedef T first_argument_type;  typedef T second_argument_type;` -- that's old, modern C++ does not have it

Comment: In general, a functor (function object) can carry state, and additional information of use to the function it is passed to (e.g. typedefs), and a pointer to a function cannot.   One specific advantage of passing (templated) functors by value as template argument is that the compiler has the opportunity to do inlining, which is often not feasible with function pointers - and that (assuming a modern optimising compiler) often gives a run-time performance advantage.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [why is std::less a functor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18700731/why-is-stdless-a-functor)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Primarily to use it as a template parameter, like `std::set<int, std::less<int>>`.

Class template parameter in interfaces like `std::set` is used instead of pointer to function to be able to pass other function-like objects that *do* have some data members. In addition, making it a template parameter aids compiler optimizations, although modern compilers can optimize away function pointers in certain cases either.

Comment: In addition `std::less</*void*/>` (which allows *transparent* comparison) wouldn't match with pointer of function (it would be a full overload set).

Comment: @Jarod42: That is true, but not the rationale for the original choice - the specialization wasn't in C++98.