# Inlinging of a user-specified function

Tags: c++, function, inlining

I'm currently writing a simulation software. I have a relatively complex operator to compute, with several parameters. One of the parameters can be a user-specified, nonlinear function. Something like:

```
double op(double param1, double param2, ..., function<double(double)> fct){
   ...
}
```

Since the function will be called several times, I would like to enable the compiler to inline the function. Fortunately, the function can be hardcoded when calling `op`. Sou I will always have something like `op(1.0, 2.0, ..., nonlinear1)` where `nonlinear1` is the name of the function and not a variable or something.

I was thinking about two ideas:

1. Function pointer `double (*)(double)`: Won't work.
2. Template parameter:

As follows:

```
template <function<double(double)> FCT> 
double op(double param1, double param2, ...){
   ...
   double a = FCT(param2);
   ...
}
```

This seems to work at a first glance, but does the compiler actually know the function behind the FCT object or does it just see a function pointer and return/argument specification?

How else could I achieve what I want?

Comment: `double (*) (double)` should compile whereas `template<std::function<double(double)>>` should not.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6451866/why-use-functors-over-functions

Answer (score 0):

You may use normal template parameter like:

```
template <typename FUNCTOR>
double op(double param1, double param2, ..., FUNCTOR fct){
   ...
}
```