# Why overload operator() in a struct

Tags: c++, boost

I have read some boost::thread code and found a lot of overloads of operator() in a struct. For instance, in boost/thread/thread_functors.hpp, you can see something like this:

```
  struct detach
  {
    void operator()(thread& t)
    {
      t.detach();
    }
  };
```

I don't understand what the benefits are. Why not use functions like

```
void detach(thread& t) {...}
```

instead?

Comment: See [why override operator()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/317450/why-override-operator)

Comment: thanks, it has been asked indeed.

Comment: Supplementary reading: [Why use functors over functions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6451866/why-use-functors-over-functions)