# Passing inline functions as arguments

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm wondering if C++ will still obey the `inline` keyword when a function is passed as an agument. In the following example, would a new frame for `onFrame` be pushed onto the stack every time `frame()` is called in the `while` loop?

```
bool interrupt = false;

void run(std::function<void()> frame) {
    while(!interrupt) frame();
}

inline void onFrame() {
    // do something each frame
}

int main() {
    run(onFrame);
}
```

Or would changing to this have any effect?

```
void run(std::function<inline void()> frame) {
    while(!interrupt) frame();
}
```

If you have no definitive answer, can you help me find a way to test this? Possibly using memory addresses or some sort of debugger?

Comment: [inline does not mean what you think it does](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1759300/212858).

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6451866/why-use-functors-over-functions

Comment: But what does this mean then? "*The intent of the inline keyword is to serve as an indicator to the optimizer that inline substitution of the function is preferred over function call, that is, instead of executing the call CPU instruction to transfer control to the function body, a copy of the function body is executed without generating the call.*" http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline

Comment: As in my reply to the other copy of this comment: `intent != effect`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> still obey the `inline` keyword ... would a new frame ... be pushed onto the stack

That isn't what the `inline` keyword does in the first place (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1759300/212858) for extensive reference).

---

Assuming, as Barry does, that you're hoping to persuade the optimiser to inline your function call (once more for luck: this is nothing to do with the `inline` keyword), function template+lambda is probably the way to go.

To see why this is, consider what the optimiser has to work with in each of these cases:

1. function template + lambda

   ```
   template <typename F>
   void run(F frame) { while(!interrupt) frame(); }

   // ... call site ...
   run([]{ onFrame(); });
   ```

   here, the function only exists at all (is instantiated from the template) at the call site, with everything the optimizer needs to work in scope and well-defined.

   Note the optimizer may still reasonably choose not to inline a call if it thinks the extra instruction cache pressure will outweigh the saving of stack frame
2. function pointer

   ```
   void run(void (*frame)()) { while(!interrupt) frame(); }

   // ... call site ...
   run(onFrame);
   ```

   here, `run` may have to be compiled as a standalone function (although that copy may be thrown away by the linker if it can prove no-one used it), and same for `onFrame`, especially since its address is taken. Finally, the optimizer may need to consider whether `run` is called with many different function pointers, or just one, when deciding whether to inline these calls. Overall, it seems like more work, and may end up as a link-time optimisation.

   NB. I used "standalone function" to mean the compiler likely emits the code & symbol table entry for a normal free function in both cases.
3. `std::function`

   This is already getting long. Let's just notice that this class goes to great lengths (the *type erasure* Barry mentioned) to make the function

   ```
   void run(std::function<void()> frame);
   ```

   *not* depend on the exact type of the function, which means hiding information from the compiler at the point it generates the code for `run`, which means less for the optimiser to work with (or conversely, more work required to undo all that careful information hiding).

---

As for *testing* what your optimiser does, you need to examine this in the context of your whole program: it's free to choose different heuristics depending on code size and complexity.

To be totally sure what it *actually did*, just disassemble with source or compile to assembler. (Yes, that's potentially a big "just", but it's platform-specific, not really on-topic for the question, and a skill worth learning anyway).

Comment: But what does this mean then? "*The intent of the inline keyword is to serve as an indicator to the optimizer that inline substitution of the function is preferred over function call, that is, instead of executing the call CPU instruction to transfer control to the function body, a copy of the function body is executed without generating the call.*" http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline

Comment: Read the paragraph immediately after the one you quoted. The only _binding_ requirement is on linkage, and it's only a hint w.r.t the actual call site.

Comment: Thank you for all your help. I do have a problem with saying "That isn't what the `inline` keyword does in the first place". I feel that we should merely explain that compilers choose to implement the feature in a certain way rather than making a general statement about the language.

Comment: I think, the best form for case 1 is `template <typename F> void run(F&& frame)`, it prevents the copy of the function object.
<code>
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    A() {}
    A(const A&) {
        std::cout << "copied" << std::endl;
    }
};

template<typename F>
void f1(F&& f) {
    f();
}

template<typename F>
void f2(F&& f) {
    f1(f);
}

int main()
{
    f2([a = A()] {});
    return 0;
}
</code>

Comment: A lambda with a non-empty capture is substantially different than one with an empty capture (stateful vs. stateless), so may not be a useful demonstration that any copying really happened in the original.

Answer (score 8):

It's going to be pretty hard for the compiler to inline your function if it has to go through `std::function`'s type-erased dispatch to get there. It's possible it'll happen anyway, but you're making it as hard as possible. Your proposed alternative (taking a `std::function<inline void()>` argument) is ill-formed.

If you don't need type erasure, don't use type erasure. `run()` can simply take an arbitrary callable:

```
template <class F>
void run(F frame) {
    while(!interrupt) frame();
}
```

That is *muuch* easier to inline for the compiler. Although, simply having an `inline` function does not in of itself guarantee that the function gets inlined. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1759575/2069064).

Note also that when you're passing a function pointer, that also makes it less likely to get inlined, which is awkward. I'm trying to find an answer on here that had a great example, but until then, if inlining is super important, wrapping it in a lambda may be the way to go:

```
run([]{ onFrame(); });
```

Answer (score 0):

Compile for release and check the list files, or turn on disassembly in debugger. Best way to know is to check the generated code.