# When should you ever use functions over functors in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11

Functors are apparently more efficient since the compiler is more easily able to inline them, and they work much better with parametrization. When should you ever use a plain old function over a functor?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why use functors over functions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6451866/why-use-functors-over-functions)

Comment: Kind of - I read the entirety of that thread before posting, and began to wonder about the other way round. Why ever use functions over functors?

Comment: Compare `v.size()` to `v.size_getter()()`.

Comment: Would you mind clarifying? Also, I don't mean in place of any built in/stl functions, I mean why should I ever write a function instead of just making it a functor.

Comment: Well, as my hypothetical example shows, there are lots of things that are perfectly well handled by functions.

Comment: I know there are; I'm asking if functions have any actual advantages over functors or are they at most interchangable?

Comment: I think it's just the case that functions are simpler to write and use. If you don't need any of the extra features that a functor provides, write a function. To use functors, you have to define a new class for each one.

Comment: To be pedantic, how would you define a functor class without using functions?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Functions support distributed overriding.  Functors do not.  You must define all of the overloads of a Functor within itself; you can add new overloads of a function *anywhere*.

Functions support ADL (argument dependent lookup), permitting overloading in the argument-type associated namespace.  Functors do not.

Function pointers are (kind of) a type-erased stateless functor that is a POD, as evidenced by how stateless lambdas convert into it.  Such features (POD, stateless, type erasure) are useful.

Comment: thank you very much, this is exactly the type of answer I was looking for

Comment: Function pointers aren't type erased, it actually takes a bit of work extraneous work to erase class memeber function pointers type. See here: https://godbolt.org/g/OS0u45

Comment: @TheSombreroKid First, I was talking about function pointers, not member function pointers (which are a different kettle of pointers).  Take `[]{}` and convert it to `void(*)()` -- that is a "kind of type erasure", in that we forget the exact operation we are doing, and just remember "we can call it with `()`.  What it can kind of "erase" is highly limited.  And I do mean "kind of" as opposed to "actually".  Edited for clarity.